# Run cloud function on pubsub message arrival using Terraform

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

#### Requirement

Need to create Terraform IAC to run cloud function on pubsub event_trigger.
I don't need to create the pubsub resources in my iac because it was created by other team.

#### My try 1

```
  event_trigger {
      event_type    = "google.pubsub.topic.publish"
      resource   = "project/${var.project_id}/topics/${var.environment}_my_topic"
  }
```

error on try1

```
│ Error: googleapi: Error 400: The request has errors
│ Details:
│ [
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
│     "fieldViolations": [
│       {
│         "description": "Pub/Sub topic name projects/myprojectID/topics/project/myprojectID/topics/my_topic does not match the expected pattern",
│         "field": "pubsub_topic"
│       }
│     ]
│   }
│ ]
│ , badRequest
```

#### My try 2

```
  event_trigger {
      event_type    = "google.pubsub.topic.publish"
      resource = {
        service = "pubsub.googleapis.com"
        name = "project/${var.project_id}/topics/${var.environment}_my_topic"
        type = "type.googleapis.com/google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage"
        }
  }
```

error on try2

```
│     │ var.environment is a string, known only after apply
│     │ var.project_id is a string, known only after apply
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "resource": string required.
```

Please help

Comment: Include the entire HCL as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Your errors depend on HCL that you do not include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected the resource path.

It should be starting with `projects/...`

My try1 has been changed like this and it worked.

```
  event_trigger {
      event_type    = "google.pubsub.topic.publish"
      resource   = "projects/${var.project_id}/topics/${var.environment}_my_topic"
  }
```